# How to solve this problem in Mathematica?

Tags: string-manipulation, number-theory, logic

Let's say we have some 4-character strings:

```
fxhg
eagc
aceh
chbe
beca
```

From those strings we want to get the correct passcode. Each of the string contains two correct passcode characters but not in the correct position. How can we get the correct **4-character** passcode?

Comment: I ask myself, provided this problem has the solution, is it really right to help anyone to get it? The question looks quite close to be criminal. I vote to close it.

Comment: Oh no @AlexeiBoulbitch, it has nothing to do with criminal! It's simply a math problem. I can do it manually to find the correct answer. I just want to know how to do it in Mathematica. Purely out of curiosity!

Comment: I'm so sorry giving you the feeling. I swear to God, it's just a math problem. I found this problem on a picture posted by someone on the web.

Comment: I have no suspects personally against you. The problem, however, seems me to have such a potential in itself, and may be used by others.

Comment: I don't think so. Think about it, if you want to crack some password, how can you get clues like those in the problem?

Comment: Is there any serious application that is still using four-letter passcodes?

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the given words as strings.  Separate the letters into character sets with `Characters[]`.  Find the universal set of all characters with `Union[]`.  Find the 4-character subsets of the universal set with `Subsets[]`.  These `trials` are the passwords character sets to try.

```
s = {"fxhg", "eagc", "aceh", "chbe", "beca"}
chsets = Characters /@ s;
univ = Union@Flatten[chsets];
trials = Subsets[univ, {4}];
```

Define a function `test[]` that will test each of `trials` to make sure it has exactly 2 characters in each of the 5 strings.  Use the `test[]` function to select sets from trials that meet the 2 character requirement.  Find all permutations of each of the sets.  These are possible passwords.

```
test[word_] := And @@ (
   (Length[Intersection[word, chsets[[#]]]] == 2) & /@ Range[5])
poss = Flatten[Permutations[#] & /@ Select[trials, test[#] &], 1]
```

Define a function `compare[]` that compares each possible password to the given strings.  We know 2 characters will be the same.  This comparison is to see if any of the same characters occur in the same position in any of the 5 given strings.  We select from the possible words only those for which the comparison is false.  That is, only for possible passwords that have no letters in the same position as in the given strings.

```
compare[word_] := Or @@ ((Or @@ MapThread[Equal,
        {word, chsets[[#]]}]) & /@ Range[5])
Select[poss, Not[compare[#]] &]
```

And the answer is ...